# What does "big ideas" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> With **big ideas** about originality, postmodernism, and the dire state of the world wafting from the record and circling our conversation, I offer up a theory about how Being Funny fits into the 1975’s project at large. If “Love It If We Made It” was a last-ditch plea for hope, the ensuing four years, filled with ever-worsening climate catastrophes, war, and major democracies in decline, all lead to one conclusion: We will not make it. But Being Funny, with all of its comfortably familiar sounds, its relatable expressions of joy and sorrow, seems to say: Let’s try to cling onto what we can in the meantime. Healy nods slowly. “That’s exactly it,” he says. “The fertility that is required for new ideas is the future, and we don’t really have the future, so we don’t have that many new ideas. That’s maybe why our record sounds like it does.”

I’d like to know what “big ideas” means in this case. Does it mean that impractical ideas to actually solve the problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Big idea" idiomatically can mean a few things.

Sometimes it can mean *the overall concept* of something - for example, "*what's the big idea?*"

In your example, it really means '*ambitious*' ideas. Context and tone determine whether the speaker means that in a positive or negative way. In one context it might imply that the ideas are ambitious in an exciting or daring way; in another context, it could mean that they are overly ambitious and expected to fail. As the first person in your quote is speaking about their *own* 'big ideas', it seems unlikely they are suggesting they are overly ambitious.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the explanation.